# Cómo se pueden leer dos o más feed RSS a la vez en Android

Tags: android, xml, rss

Tengo este código que lee un XML y lo muestra por pantalla.

```
private void setListData() {
    String url = "url_feed";
    listaArticulos = new ArrayList();
    CargarXml cx = new CargarXml();
    cx.execute(url);
}

private class CargarXml extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... paramVarArgs) {
        XmlParserSax localXmlParserSax = new XmlParserSax(paramVarArgs[0]);
        Log.d("URL", paramVarArgs[0]);
        xml = localXmlParserSax.parse();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (xml != null && xml.size() > 0) {
            for(int i=0; i < xml.size(); i++) {
                Tecnologia tecnologia = new Tecnologia();
                tecnologia.setTitle(xml.get(i).getTitle());
                Log.e("Result_" + i, xml.get(i).getTitle());

                listaArticulos.add(tecnologia);
            }
        }

        Resources res = getResources();
        adapter = new TecnologiaAdapter(TecnologiaF, listaArticulos, res, "Tecnologia");
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero es poder tener un array con las noticias de 2 o mas feeds RSS. Actualmente solo lo tengo con uno y no sé cómo añadir más al array.

Comment: ¿Los otros items del otro feed, los almacenas en otro `ArrayList`? ¿Has probado después de obtener tu segundo feed, usar `listaArticulos.add(primerArryList);` para unir ambos, y después mostrarlos en pantalla.?

Comment: No entiendo lo que deseas, que array de items segun tu código?

Comment: Lo que quiero es almacenar en un array las noticias de 2 feeds distintos @Jorgesys

Comment: Supongo que lo que podrás hacer será obtener cada feed en un array y luego juntarlos en un único array ordenandolos por fecha.

Comment: El problema es que cuando leo un rss, los muestro mediante un custom view, no se como mostrar el custom view despues @Joacer

Comment: Supongo que si los dos RSS o los que sean tienen la misma estructura para cada elemento, igual podrías obtener todos los feeds en el mismo AsyncTask y juntarlos  y luego mostrarlos en en tu custom view, pero si los elementos de tus feeds no siguen la misma estructura, me parece que será un poco dificil

Comment: Lo intentaré de la forma que dices, Muchas gracias @Joacer

Comment: De nada, si lo consigues resolver publica una respuesta con tu solución para que le pueda servir a más gente